# Cannot access ListField elements from another python code

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

Hello I want to share a mongodb between two django apps (monitor , manager) using one application called common.

I can create database instances in the manager application easily but when accessing the book authors i cannot.

it return this error

> mongoengine.errors.FieldDoesNotExist: The fields "{'_id'}" do not
>   exist on the document "author"

**models.py**

```
from mongoengine import *

class author(Document):
   name = StringField(required = True)
   meta = {'abstract': True , 'allow_inheritance':True}


class book(Document):
   name = StringField(required = True)
   authors = ListField(ReferenceField(author))
   meta = {'abstract': True , 'allow_inheritance':True}
```

**manager.py**

```
from mongoengine import * 
from models import * 

class author(author):
    def rand(self):
        print("i am useless")
class book(book):
    def rand2(self):
        print("i am also useless")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect('test', host = '0.0.0.0',port = 27017)
    a1 = author(name = "Charef")
    a1.save()
    a2 = author(name = "hamid")
    a2.save()
    a3 = author(name = "djoudi")
    a3.save()
    a4 = author(name = "cheb khaled")
    a4.save()
    book1_authors = [a1,a2,a4]
    book2_authors = [a1,a3]


    book1 = book(name = "Hello Django", authors = book1_authors)
    book1.save()

    book2 = book(name = "Hello python", authors = book2_authors)
    book2.save()
```

**monitor**

```
from mongoengine import * 
from models import * 

class author(author):
    def say_hi(self):
        print("Hi, my name is {} and this is my book".format(self.name))

class book(book):
    def book_info(self):
        for author in self.authors:
            print(author.say_hi())
            print("done !! ")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect("test",host = "0.0.0.0", port = 27017)
    s_book = book.objects()[0]
    print(s_book.name)
    print(len(s_book.authors))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unique names for the different classes (e.g. `BaseBook` for the abstract class and `Book` for the concrete class). Some internals of mongoengine relies on the uniqueness of the class names so it's not a good idea to go against that.

Using the following works:

```py
class BaseAuthor(Document):
   name = StringField(required=True)
   meta = {'abstract': True , 'allow_inheritance':True}


class BaseBook(Document):
   name = StringField(required=True)
   authors = ListField(ReferenceField(BaseAuthor))
   meta = {'abstract': True , 'allow_inheritance':True}

class Author(BaseAuthor):
    def rand(self):
        print("i am useless")

class Book(BaseBook):
    def rand2(self):
        print("i am also useless")
```

Also, if possible use the same `Book/Author` classes in both monitor and manager

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply, but we need the same name to make the database visible for other apps. because when use another name it will changes the cls name in mongodb.

Comment: The abstract class don't appear in the `_cls` so you can use another name for that one (e.g `AbstractAuthor` or `BaseAuthor`). Regarding the actual Author class, I was suggesting that you use the same class from your manager & monitor module, i.e define the Author class in your models.py